# find values of json array using postgresql query

Tags: json, postgresql

This is my JSON value

```
"order": {
        "items": [{
            "amount": 30000,
            "product_name": "product A",
            "quantity": 3,
         }, {
            "amount": 1000,
            "product_name": "product B",
            "quantity": 1,
        }],
        "currency": "USD"
    }
```

I want get values of amount from the array using mysql queries. I tried select json_extract_path_text('order','items') but it fetches whole value

```
 [{
            "amount": 30000,
            "product_name": "product A",
            "quantity": 3,
         }, {
            "amount": 1000,
            "product_name": "product B",
            "quantity": 1,
        }]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This is why you don’t store JSON in database tables.

Comment: Does MySQL support querying JSON? Didn't you mean PostreSQL?

Comment: @ Mosty Mostacho Thanks for notify this. I made a great mistake. You are right Its postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_array_elements()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function:

```
select
    (value->>'amount')::int as amount
from json_array_elements(
    '{"order":
         {  "items": [
                {"amount": 30000,"product_name": "product A", "quantity": 3},
                {"amount": 1000,"product_name": "product B","quantity": 1}
            ],
            "currency": "USD"}
     }'::json->'order'->'items'
)
```